# post multiple value as variable in function

Tags: php, function, php-7

I'm trying to send multiple values from select in register form into function as variable to do the insert. I try using `foreach()` to send the values as variable but it's only send the last value, not all selected value in select from the form.

```
function addnew()
{
  $values = false;
  if (!empty($_POST['values'])) {
   $value = $_POST['values'];
   foreach($_POST['values'] as $value){
    echo "Value is:".$value."</br>";
   }
  }
}
```

Is my code error or there are other way to send multiple value via function?

EDIT:
Here is my complete HTML page (adjusted for this case)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1561.4">

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="submit.php?addvalue"> <!-- my action url is custom for calling function -->
<select name="values[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php 
function addvalue()
{
    $values = false;
    if (!empty($_POST['values'])) {
        $values = $_POST['values'];
        foreach($_POST['values'] as $value){                
            echo "Value is:".$value."</br>";
           }
    }

    $data['value'] = $value;

    $model = new otherfucntion(); //class that contain other function
    $result = $model->addValue($data); //other function that do the query
    if ($result)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('".$value."</br>');</script>";//alert show value
        }
}

class otherfunction //on my case, this in otherfunction.php
{
    function conn()
    {
        //connection to db here
    }
    function addValue(($data=array()) 
    {
        extract($data);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (value) VALUES ('$value')";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->conn(), $sql);
            if (!empty($result))
            {
                return $result;
            }           
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you could spare us the parts of your code which is absolutely not involved in the $_POST extraction? Also as I said in my answer, you must use the full name of the HTML variable, which is `values[]`, as the key in your $_POST array. You must extract `$_POST['values[]']`, which is itself of type array (if defined).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_POST['values[]']`

and use the same in your HTML:

`<... name="values[]">`

Comment: Already use `<... name="values[]">` in HTML, which `$_POST` should I try `$_POST['values[]']`? Try at all variable it's give me empty value in echo.

Comment: Please post your well-formatted HTML form snippet, and also a dump of your `$_POST` array?

Comment: how to use snippet? I've Google it, they say there are button when post a question. Should I edit my post to enable snippet? Also, I'm never use `var_dump($_POST['$values'])` before, tried it and I got only `</br>`.

Comment: My problem is solved, by using `<... name="values[]">` at HTML page only, and I move `foreach($_POST['values'] as $value){` from 1st function into 2nd function:
`foreach ($data['value'] as $value) {
   //query to insert
  }`
Thanks.

Comment: `$data['value']` being? …

Comment: Since I send multiple value to `$_POST['values']` in 1st function as array and declare it as `$data['value'] = $value;`, then I pass that value to 2nd function with `extract($data);` it's still known as  `$data['value'] = $value;` in array type. Then I use foreach to do the insert query.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code

In your html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1561.4">

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="submit.php">  
<select name="values[]">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="1"></option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In submit.php file

```
<?php 
foreach($_POST['values'] as $value){
 echo "Value is:".$value."</br>";
}
?>
```

Hope It Helps.

Thanks

Comment: Test using your code, it give me **Notice: Undefined index: values in** and **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in** error. Also i try to change the code into:
`<select name="values[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>` which is I'm using right now, also give me the same error.

Comment: My mistake, I already change the code. And yes, it did give me the expecting result. But, since I'm using function in class, it's failed to pass the all the value into variable in the function.

Comment: There is no rational in using several `select` with the same `name="values[]"` attribute.